# How to access "id" selector via Ruby ScriptingBridge

Tags: ruby, macos, applescript, scripting-bridge

I'm trying to get a list of running processes on OS X through Ruby's ScriptingBridge.

Everything works fine, except getting the process id. The problem seems to be that Ruby's internal Object#id property is called instead of the SystemEvents.process.id selector.

This is my current sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Lists all active processes

require 'osx/cocoa'
include OSX
OSX.require_framework 'ScriptingBridge'

app = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.SystemEvents")
procs = app.processes

procs.each do |x|
    puts "Process No. #{x.id}: #{x.name}"
end
```

This is (part of) it's output:

```
merlin:mw ~/> /Users/mw/Projekte/Ruby/winlist.rb 
/Users/mw/Projekte/Python/winlist.rb:13: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
Process No. 2275604960: loginwindow
/Users/mw/Projekte/Python/winlist.rb:13: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
Process No. 2275603460: talagent
/Users/mw/Projekte/Python/winlist.rb:13: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
Process No. 2275600720: Dock
[... snipped list of all my processes ...]
```

How can I make sure the ScriptingBridge is called, not Object#id?

Comment: Maybe upgrade? `Object#id` does not exist anymore in Ruby 1.9

Comment: I was looking for a more general solution, but as there probably isn't one, I'll definitively give that a try. For the moment, I've just switched over to Python ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Scripting Bridge is flawed and often prone to application incompatibilities and other problems. Consider using AppleScript (either directly or via NSAppleScript, osascript, or AppleScriptObjC) instead.
2. If you're using Cocoa or other system APIs to get information from System Events.app, you're doing it wrong. SE is just an AppleScript wrapper around those same APIs. In this case, use NSWorkspace:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env ruby

   # Lists all active processes

   require 'osx/cocoa'
   include OSX

   procs = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.runningApplications

   procs.each do |x|
       puts "Process No. #{x.processIdentifier} Name. #{x.localizedName}"
   end
   ```

Comment: Okay, this doesn't really help me, because NSRunningApplication doesn't seem to have the `windows` property I need as well. I'll just mark it as answered because I solved it otherwise.